# order by problems - mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table 'sharelist' with the following attributes

```
linkID
bool1
bool2
bool3
activityTime
```

linkID and activityTime are ints. bool1-3 are booleans.

I need a query which will first group together rows based on linkID (simple GROUP BY statement). The hard part is the ordering. Lets say rows 1-5 from 'sharelist' have the same value for linkID and are therefore combined into one entry in the resulting table. If any of those 5 rows have a value of true for either bool1, bool2, or bool3, then the entire group is considered "new". Otherwise the group is considered "old". In addition, for each group, the maximum activityTime should be stored.

I want the resulting table to have all the "new" groups first ordered by the maximum activityTime, and then all the "old" groups ordered by the maximum activityTime. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT linkID, MAX(activityTime) 
FROM sharelist
GROUP BY linkID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an expression in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT linkID, MAX(activityTime) 
FROM sharelist
GROUP BY linkID
ORDER BY (bool1 or bool2 or bool3) desc, max(activityTime)
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers, so you can actually order by the number of true expressions:

```
SELECT linkID, MAX(activityTime) 
FROM sharelist
GROUP BY linkID
ORDER BY (bool1 > 0) + (bool2 > 0) + (bool3 > 0) desc, max(activityTime)
```

Comment: Does this factor in the requirement on activityTime?